# Aligning div right next to the list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create `div` elements and print items on to them dynamically. I've created [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y44dR/3/) to show where I've reached.

The issue with my code is that it doesn't show up right next to the list where I want it. Instead it is displayed at the bottom. Is it possible to show the new `div` right next to the element that I'm hovering over?

```
$(".bubble").live({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $("#bubble").show();
        $("#bubble").html($(this).attr('id'));
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $("#bubble").empty();
    }
});
```

```css
#bubble{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#666666;
    position:absolute;
    display:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span class="bubble" id="test1">test1</span></li>
    <li><span class="bubble" id="test2">test2</span></li>
    <li><span class="bubble" id="test3">test3</span></li>
    <li><span class="bubble" id="test4">test4</span></li>
    <li><span class="bubble" id="test5">test5</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="bubble"></div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set the position of `#bubble` relative to the `li` which is being moused over. Try this:

```
$("ul").on('hover', '.bubble', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        var $el = $(this);
        $("#bubble")
            .html($el.attr('id'))
            .css({
                top: $el.offset().top,
                left: $el.offset().left + $el.width()
            })
            .show();
    }
    else {
        $("#bubble").empty();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y44dR/23/)

Note that I have removed the use of `live()` as it has been deprecated, and used `on()` with a delegate instead. Also I used the `hover` event.

Comment: but if the div is being created dynamically,, the on only works for first time...

Comment: @user1371896 not true, I'm using `on()` with a delegated handler, so it will behave as `live()` does but with better performance.

Comment: will surely check and let you knw

Answer (score 11):

What about a pure CSS solution?

*HTML:*

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span class="bubble" id="test1">test1</span>
    <div>test1</div>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="bubble" id="test2">test2</span>
    <div>test2</div>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="bubble" id="test3">test3</span>
    <div>test3</div>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="bubble" id="test4">test4</span>
    <div>test4</div>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="bubble" id="test5">test5</span>
    <div>test5</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
ul li div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #666666;
    position: absolute;  
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover div {
    display: inline;   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H2ZMc/

Comment: Of all provided solutions I definitely prefer this one and it even works in IE7! Nice!

Comment: @SaschaM78 thank you, kind sir. I usually prefer solutions that break IE7 :P but in this case I shall make an exception.

Comment: The OP's question states: *I am trying to create div elements and **print** items on to them*. The problem with your pure CSS solution is that you can't print the item on to the highlighted `div`. Impressive work though!

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps:

**[JS-Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aki143S/y44dR/16/)**

I append the #bubble to the li

```
$(".bubble").live({
           mouseenter : function() {
               $("#bubble").html($(this).attr('id'));
               $(this).append($("#bubble").show());               
            },
            mouseleave : function() {
             $("#bubble").empty().hide();

            }
  });
```

Comment: +1 though `display:inline-block` is problematic in IE7 without some dirty little hacks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var bubble = $("#bubble");

$(".bubble").live({
    mouseenter : function(e) {    
        $("#bubble").html($(this).attr('id'));
        e.target.appendChild(bubble);
    },

    mouseleave : function() {
        $("#bubble").empty();        
    }
});
```

What this does is appends the bubble element to the element on which the mouse is over. By applying `display: inline` to the `div` you can make it appear beside its sibling instead of below it as it will do if you use this code directly.

Answer (score 2):

Do what Mica said and also remove the position:absolute;

So css should be

```
#bubble{
width:100px;
height:10px; 
background-color:#666666;
display:hidden;
display: inline;
float: left;
}

ul{
display: inline;
float: left;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y44dR/21/

Answer (score 2):

Why use `.on()` when the `#bubble` element already exists.

```
$(".bubble").hover( function( ) {

    var offset = $(this).offset();

    $("#bubble").html($(this).attr("id"))
        .css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left + $(this).width() })
        .show();
}, function( ) {
    $("#bubble").html("").hide();
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/y44dR/24/)

Comment: Then just use `left: offset.left - $("#bubble").width()` to set the left css property. Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/y44dR/25/)

Answer (score 1):

If you give the `<ul>` and the `<div>` the following styles it should work.

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```

Comment: maybe i didn't understand you problem correctly but the following css rule works for me: `ul, div  { float: left; display: inline }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".bubble").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("#bubble").show();
        $("#bubble").html($(this).attr('id'));

        var p = $(this).position();
        $("#bubble").css({left: p.left + $(this).outerWidth(), top: p.top });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#bubble").empty().css({top: '', left: ''});
    }
});​
```

Comment: No less than 10 jQuery objects used, with 7 of them using the same selector... good grief!

Comment: thanks for your comment. I never thought about that. It'll improve my style!

Comment: No problem, the real beauty of jQuery is the ability to chain, so `$('#bubble').empty().css({"top" : '', "left" : ''});` would achieve the same thing with only one jQuery object as overhead:)